# How to connect with health center to IBM J9 7 on AIX

Tags: java, jvm, aix, health-monitoring

I want to connect to a Java J9 JVM version 7 which runs on AIX.
The Java application is configured to enable the health center agent and the system reports that the JMX port is opened.
But when i Start the health center client, which i installed via the update site to my Eclipse instance, enter the host name and port number to the JMX connection wizard, it starts to scan from the port i specified up to portnr+100, and then it says that he could not find a JVM.

Am i missing something?

Java version on AIX

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6470_27-20131115_04)
IBM J9 VM (build 2.7, JRE 1.7.0 AIX ppc64-64 Compressed References 20131114_175264 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R27_Java727_GA_20131114_0833_B175264
JIT  - tr.r13.java_20131113_50523
GC   - R27_Java727_GA_20131114_0833_B175264_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20131114_175264)
JCL - 20131113_01 based on Oracle 7u45-b18de here
```

Command line for starting the Java application

```
java -Xmn100m -Xms400m -Xmx400m -Xhealthcenter ...
```

Log of JVM regarding health center agent

```
Mar 18, 2016 6:15:09 PM com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.agent.mbean.HCLaunchMBean <init>
INFO: Agent version "2.2.0.20131003"
Mar 18, 2016 6:15:09 PM com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.agent.mbean.HCLaunchMBean startMBeanServer
INFO: IIOP will be listening on the next available system assigned port. Use com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.agent.iiop.port to specify a port 
Mar 18, 2016 6:15:09 PM com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.agent.mbean.HCLaunchMBean startAgent
INFO: Health Center agent started on port 1972.
```

Agent port open on server machine

```
(1) machine:user1:/home/user1> lsof -nP | grep LISTEN | grep 1972
java      30474378 user1   77u  IPv6 0xf1000e000a345bb8                0t0         TCP *:1972 (LISTEN)

(1) machine:user1:/home/user1> ps ax | grep 30474378
 24707098  pts/3 A     0:00 grep 30474378 
 30474378      - A     0:13 /usr/bin/java -Xmn100m -Xms400m -Xmx400m -Xhealthcenter -

(1) machine:user1:/home/user1>
```

Port open from client machine:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-18 18:19 BRT
Nmap scan report for machine (172.1.1.10)
Host is up (0.024s latency).
Not shown: 973 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
...
1972/tcp  open  intersys-cache
...

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.24 seconds
```

EDIT: i realized that the opened port on the AIX machine listened on IPv6. I added the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` property and then the agent started to listen on an IPv4 port:

```
(1) machine:user1:/home/user1/log> lsof -nP | grep LISTEN | grep IPv4 | grep 1972
java      57016438 user1   77u  IPv4 0xf1000e0004dbd3b8                0t0         TCP *:1972 (LISTEN)

(1) machine:user1:/home/user1/log>
```

But, however, the health center client does not find a JVM on that port

Comment: something as simple as a firewall?  what does a packet capture on the client-side say?

Answer (score 0):

The Health Center agent that came packaged with that JVM is pretty old (nearly 3 1/2 years old). Can you follow the instructions on https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.doc/topics/installingagent.html to upgrade the agent to the latest version and see if the problem still occurs?